# replace multiple substring with REPLACE function - SPSS modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I'm trying to replace multiple keywords in a string with the same character. I can't find the correct expression to replace more than one substring with the string.

I tried replace("keyword1" and "keyworkd2", "$", stringextraction). Also tried

replace("keyword1"|"keyworkd2", "$", stringextraction)
(replace("keyword1", "$", stringextraction) and (replace("keyword2","$", stringextraction)
etc...

any way to replace multiple substrings with the same character in one expression in spss modeler? Thanks